# How to add actions to UIAlertController and get result of actions (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uialertcontroller

I want to set up a `UIAlertController` with four action buttons, and the titles of the buttons to be set to "hearts", "spades", "diamonds", and "clubs". When a button is pressed, I want to return its title.

In short, here is my plan:

```
// TODO: Create a new alert controller

for i in ["hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "clubs"] {

    // TODO: Add action button to alert controller

    // TODO: Set title of button to i

}

// TODO: return currentTitle() of action button that was clicked
```

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried, what problems did it have, and what did you find when trying to debug those problems?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message: "Alert Message", style = .Alert)
for i in ["hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "hearts"] {
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: i, style: .Default, handler: doSomething)
}
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And handle the action here:

```
func doSomething(action: UIAlertAction) {
    //Use action.title
}
```

For future reference, you should take a look at [Apple's Documentation on UIAlertControllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/)

Comment: Is there any way to get the action of button by tags or index?

Answer (score 20):

here´s a sample code with two actions plus and ok-action:

```
import UIKit

// The UIAlertControllerStyle ActionSheet is used when there are more than one button.
@IBAction func moreActionsButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let otherAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Multiple Actions", message: "The alert has more than one action which means more than one button.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    let printSomething = UIAlertAction(title: "Print", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { _ in
        print("We can run a block of code." )
    }

    let callFunction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call Function", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: myHandler)

    let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

    // relate actions to controllers
    otherAlert.addAction(printSomething)
    otherAlert.addAction(callFunction)
    otherAlert.addAction(dismiss)

    presentViewController(otherAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func myHandler(alert: UIAlertAction){
    print("You tapped: \(alert.title)")
}}
```

with i.E. **handler: myHandler** you define a function, to read the result of 
the *let printSomething*.

This is just **one** way ;-)

Any questions?

Comment: thanks! Does presentViewController show the alert?

Comment: @Abhi V yes, that´s right!